# Apache FTPClient : 530 You aren't logged in

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm using `FTPClient` of apache for getting size of specific file from my server. So, the error that I faced in android is `530 You aren't logged in`. while my code is such below and I've tested it  in pure Java. I don't know why this error occurred on Android but all things are okay in Java.

```
client.connect("my-server-ip");
client.login("username", "password");
client.setKeepAlive(true);
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

client.sendCommand("SIZE " + "file-path");

try {
    sizeStr = client.getReplyString().trim();
    this.M_fileData.M_contentLength = Long.parseLong(sizeStr.split(" ")[1]);
    System.out.println(sizeStr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    client.disconnect();
}
```

Java pure result is : `213 1757682`, while android result is `530 You aren't logged in`.

Could any one explain me how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the FTPClient.login() method does return a boolean to indicate success/failure.  You should check that to confirm that the login succeeded.  My speculation is that the login() method failed, and that is why you are getting the 530 error.

Comment: Also, according to the documentation, http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html, you can check getReplyCode() after the connect() method to confirm it connected to the server.  You can also call getReplyCode() after each action to check the response status.

Comment: @Steven Mastandrea :‌ login() return false in `android` and return true in `Java` :-/

Answer (score 1):

**-** First of all i want you to make sure you have given the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission.

Well for further reference, i am giving you the code that i used to Download music clip in my android application.

I have used the `Apache's commons library`

```
public void goforIt(){


        FTPClient con = null;

        try
        {
            con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("50.xx.xx.xx");

            if (con.login("Adminxxxxx", "KUjWbk361wobbyl-xxxxxx"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/sdcard/vivek.m4a";

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = con.retrieveFile("vivekm4a.m4a", out);
                out.close();
                if (result) Log.v("download result", "succeeded");
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("download result","failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever 530 error code return it means your username or password is incorrect. And due to login failed you cant upload file.